# Late upload of photos when you open the menu section

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[image]

Hello, as I mentioned in the title, when I go to the menu page, the photos as below are loaded late. I can do two things here I can show the upload icon until the photos are uploaded, or the photos can be uploaded while I am on another page. Can you help me how to do it?

Comment: "_upload_" - give the context of the question do you mean downloaded? "_Can you help me how to do it_" - yes but not without the implementation you have so far. The question is extremely vague at this point. Please show the relevant code.

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see a problem with the question I asked. I was expecting an answer like the one below so I didn't need to add code. Thank you everyone

Answer (score 1):

First of all, did you check the images? Are there in the correct size (thumbnails) and also compressed? It looks like that they having 2mb+ each.

May you work with classic loading animation placeholders like YouTube is doing it - while the images are loading. Also, you can check out the "lazy" attribute on an img tag, if there are even more images outside of the viewport